# How can I add a message to output files with Grunt.js?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm using grunt to compile coffeescript to javascript.  I'd like to add a short comment to the top of the output js files that state they are generated files that should not be edited, perhaps listing what .coffee file it came from.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile all your code into a single js file - you could use coffee's joining ability and join a file with your notice to the output.

If you compile each coffee script into a separate js file you could use the [`concat`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat/) task
after the compilation and prepend each of the generated files with a file containing your notice.